# facebook permissions for inbox messages gets limited answer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-messages

I've asked for read_mailbox permissions.
now I'm trying to access it with http request

`https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=inbox`

however I'm getting only 25 messages per conversation. I need all messages, does anybody know how to do it?
 I know that there are a limit\since\until parameters and paging options but still didn't manage how to use it :(

Thanks!

Comment: what happens when you ask for all the messages in a thread? are they returned? (`/THREAD_ID/messages`)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging